# Make the text Bold or Underline

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssas

Goal:
Make the country's name to have underline or bold in the textbox. Please rememeber that there are lots of country's name in the list.

Problem:
How should I enable to make the country's name to have underline or bold only?

Information:
The data source is SSAS.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [Placeholders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207048.aspx) at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Placeholders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207048.aspx). To use placeholders in your cell, click on where it shows `<<Expr>>` so it is highlighted then right-click it and choose `Placeholder Properties...`. On the `General` tab select the radio button to activate `HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles`.

So now we can use HTML tags to highlight sections of the text in the cell. Next we need a function to convert country names so they appear bold.

Create a custom code function to bold the text: from the `Report` menu, choose `Report Properties...` and click the `Code` tab. Enter the following code:

```
Function BoldCountries(Text As String) As String
  return Text.Replace("Australia", "<b>Australia</b>")
End Function
```

Okay, so that only bolds Australia. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to load a list of country names and iterate through them putting HTML bold tags around the country names.

Finally, go to your field cell and change the expression for the `` `Value `` from just the field value to calling this function with the field value:

```
=Code.BoldCountries(Fields!FieldWithCountryNames.Value)
```

Comment: is it possible to replace the text "Australia" in the source code by retrieving a list from the datasource to compare if Text is among in the list. If yes, then is shall have a bold value?

Comment: Yes, I'd declare a dynamic array and check to see if it was empty before bolding the countries. If it was empty, load the country names from a database or wherever you have them. Once loaded, you can now iterate through the countries, doing a `String.Replace` for each country in the array.